# Is "break X at the seams" a metaphor, or something else?

Tags: grammar, meaning, idiomatic-language, metaphors

> The Mariana crow actually uses its bill to peck and break the shell at
> the seams to extract the vulnerable crab.

https://corvidresearch.blog/tag/extinct-crow/

I was told it wasn't an idiom, so I am wondering if it's a valid metaphorical usage. I do see it often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Break* is literal in this context. It means

> **VERB** broke, broken 
> 1 Separate or cause to separate into pieces as a result of a blow, shock, or strain.
>
> ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/break), n. d.)

"At the seam" is an idiomatic way of saying "entirely".

> at the seams 
> : ENTIRELY, COMPLETELY 
> *falling apart at the seams*
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seam), n. d.)

Comment: Is break and break apart synonymous? It seems you can say break instead of break apart, and break apart seems more idiomatic with "at the seams".

Comment: _Break_ and _break apart_ are definitely not synonymous. I think they are both idiomatic.

Comment: I meant to say break is more general than break apart and break apart is just more specific.

Comment: "At the seams" is also literal in this context; the idiom you mentioned is not relevant.

Comment: What @randomhead said. "At the seams" here simply refers to the literal "seam" joining the carapace (top shell) to the underbelly.